# onmouseover not working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

i am working on a script to make the cursor of each user in my site to follow by an image like this :  http://nextnews.us/content/index2.php but when tried to insert the same script on wordpress template is not working and the image is staying static!

```
                <style>

                    #sendframe {

                        opacity:1.0;        
                        position:absolute;        
                        overflow:hidden;        
                        top:50;        
                        left:50;        
                    }        
                </style>        

        <script type="text/javascript">        
                    document.onmousemove = mouseMove;         
                    function mouseMove(ev){         
                        ev = ev || window.event;        
                        var mousePos = mouseCoords(ev);       
                        document.getElementById('sendframe').style.left=mousePos.x-30;         
                        document.getElementById('sendframe').style.top=mousePos.y-23;         
                    }        
                    function mouseCoords(ev){         

                        if(ev.pageX || ev.pageY){

                            return {x:ev.pageX, y:ev.pageY};

                        }

                        return {

                            x:ev.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft - document.body.clientLeft,

                            y:ev.clientY + document.body.scrollTop  - document.body.clientTop

                        };

                    }

                </script>

 <div id="sendframe" style="display: ; position: absolute; opacity:1.0;filter:alpha(opacity=1);">

    //here i will ad the image source

 </div>
```

Comment: It's not Wordpress related. Look again carefully what are you doing, I'm sure it's something very small that you are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the omission of "px" from the x and y coordinates in your CSS rules, e.g., `top:50; left:50;` and `document.getElementById('sendframe').style.left=mousePos.x-30;`

[Here is it working in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8A6bC/)

(And please try to format your code a bit better next time. It doesn't really help to have everything tabbed out out view.)